# Is it possible for multiple summons to participate in the same chase?

Tags: naruto-online

In Naruto Online, you can equip 3 summons that help you string together chases. I've tried many combinations with my ninja's chase skills and my chases never seem to utilize more than 1 summon per turn. I'm wondering if it's possible to chain something like ninja + summon + summon + ninja in a single chase or do I need to equip summons that combo PER chase.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

No this is not possible. You can only select one summon that will help you out. 
However you should always set the strongest summons in the slots you don't need since they increase your power.

Comment: So only the summon in the top slot counts right?

Comment: No. When you select your talents (don't know the english description though) you have your 3 selectet summons at the bottom. There you can select the one you want to use

Answer (score -1):

No it isn't possible you can only use the summon you select. For instance, if I have the serpent, the Flood dragon, and the illusion crow and I select the flood dragon then only the flood dragon would show up in battle.

Comment: This does not add anything new to a question that was answered two years ago

Comment: sorry just trying to get some coupons for my games